Expense Recognition and Inflation
If we follow the expense recognition principle and spread out a $5k expense by deducting $1k per year for 5 years instead of $5k in one year, then we have the problem of inflation. As the years go by, the $1k decreases in value. So in the end we are deducting less than $5k if we adjust for inflation.
This means that the business is paying more tax.
I understand that accounting for inflation in practice is unrealistic, but are businesses really willing to pay more tax, albeit indirectly? For large companies like amazon that I'm sure have a lot of big and long-term expenses, the money lost via inflation should add up to a lot.
But companies also shouldn't violate the expense recognition principle.
So how do companies handle this?

Once you spend the $5k - the amount is set, it doesn't change. You're describing depreciation - loss of value of a capital asset over time. This is usually calculated based on the price paid and a function of time, nothing else. It may not reflect the real fair market value of the asset, and that's fine. Companies routinely sell fully depreciated assets - that produces capital gains or depreciation recapture, for tax purposes.

Nitpick - spreading the cost of an expense over time is amortization, not depreciation, but your description still holds (inflation is not a consideration)

Money does not really "lose value" directly. $1 is still $1. What you can do with it changes as prices go up (which is what inflation really is) but there's not a direct measure to say $1 is worth, say, exactly $0.95.  Or, more to your point, that what cost $1 five years ago now costs $1.15, therefore I should get a bigger tax deduction. You spend $1 on it, and that's the tax deduction you get.  Taxes and accounting are based on actual costs, not market value (with a few exceptions for asset write-downs).
If a company wanted to take inflation into account for the deduction then they would have to spread the actual expense over the 5 years, which meant that they were paying more (because prices go up) to get a larger tax break.  As my father always said - it makes no sense to spend $1 to keep from sending the government 30 cents.

but are businesses really willing to pay more tax, albeit indirectly?

It doesn't really matter if they are willing or not, that's how the tax laws are written. However, they also benefit indirectly from inflation if they have fixed debt - they are paying the same amount of interest with "less valuable" money. I doubt anyone would want to take inflation into account for expense amortization if it meant that they also had to adjust their actual interest expense to inflation.
Additionally, the principal of amortization (spreading the reported cost of an expense over time) is not really about tax or inflation. It is about properly matching up the expense with the related revenue. Otherwise, the company might deduct the full cost in year one, getting a huge tax break up front, rather than spreading it out. But that would lead to 1) a very low net profit in the year of the expense, which owners may not like, and 2) artificially high profit margins in the remaining years.

You don’t have a choice
The tax depreciation of assets is a legal obligation set out in the relevant tax code. It’s not optional.
Similarly, the accounting depreciation rate will be set out in the relevant accounting standard. These typically offer more discretion than the tax code and generally follow the principle that an asset should be deprecated so that it’s depreciated value reaches zero when the asset no longer has economic value. Ideally, its depreciated value should be equal to its economic value every year along the way.
However, there is no reason why the tax value, the accounting value, the economic value, the realisable value, and the scrap value of an asset should line up.
From a cash flow perspective, the earlier you can claim a tax deduction the better, even without inflation - money now is better than money in the future. However, much as you would like to reduce your tax bill now, the government has rules about it.
